# Cannot visit ipython notebook server remotely?

Tags: ssh, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm following the [tutorial](http://minrk-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server) to put up my server. But I cannot visit the website through my browser

`https://<domain of my server>:<port>` where I have set the values to my server machine.

The browser says "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" seems like the website doesn't exist. I wonder why is that and is there additional steps outside that tutorial? Do I need to set up SSH on the server machine first ?

Comment: "seems like the website doesn't exist" `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` more likely means that you're trying to connect to the wrong server, or the server isn't running, or you're being blocked by a firewall.

Comment: And how is ssh related to this? Your browser doesn't use ssh to make http(s) connections.

Comment: @Kenster Ok, just guessing, I dont know much about how ssh works. Can you give any idea about how to check my firewall on linux?

Comment: @Kenster I'm pretty sure the server is running. And the address is <local ip of my server>:<port number I set in configure file>. So it should be alright

Comment: First you should follow the official docs (http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server) and not a fork that can be arbitrarily out of date.